# Magento 2 programmatically update product save empty value to product attribute

Tags: php, attributes, product, magento2

Updating existing product's (Magento CE 2.1.5) attributes with values that taken from csv file,  when values are not empty string there is no problem, but when try to save empty string, the product attributes value has not been updated

```
$product->setWidth("");
$product->save();
```

The result after product save is that the attribute value stays the same value, that was before update.
Tried several other methods, that where mentioned elsewhere, but no result

```
$product->setWidth("");  //does nothing
$product->setData("width",""); //does nothing
$product->unsetData("width"); //does nothing
$product->setWidth(new \Zend_Db_Expr('')); //does nothing
$product->setData("width",null); //does nothing
$product->save();
```

So question  is what is correct way to do it? So wonder what is the correct way to set magento 2.x attribute emtpy?

Comment: Found that there is bug report on csv import, so could be that problem is related to that https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7468 
Neverless from admin side there is no problem of saving the emtpy value, so have to find the right way to set value emtpy, tried add _edit_mode flag, but that did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute took the "default" value if we try to set it to null.

Use `$product->setWidth(' ')` instead, basically to set a space rather than null would solve the problem.

When gathering the data, use `if (!empty($product->getWidth())) { ... }`.